# Why is syntax highlighting missing in CLion?

Tags: ide, clion

In CLion, syntax highlighting spontaneously disappears, hints seem to remain, but the highlighting itself disappears. The backlight returns after 10 minutes or after restarting CLion. How can this be fixed?

[**CLion before**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1zsL.png)

[**CLion after**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfO6r.png)

**CLion logs:**

```
Target file: fd0/fd1/fd2/fd3/fd4/fd5/fd6.cpp
Compilation command: C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\g++.exe -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostdlibinc -ccc-no-implicit-pch-or-pth -D__JETBRAINS_IDE__=20220200L -D__CLION_IDE__=20220200L -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_QMLMODELS_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 -g -std=gnu++23 -x c++ --target=x86_64-unknown-windows-gnu -frelaxed-template-template-args -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-array-bounds -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wshadow -Wno-shadow-field-in-constructor-modified -Wno-shadow-ivar -Wuninitialized -Wunused-label -Wunused-lambda-capture -Ifd0/fd7/fd8 -Ifd0/fd7/fd8/fd9 -iquotefd0/fd1/fd2/fd3/fd4/fd5 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13/fd9 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd14/fd15 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13/fd16 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13/fd17 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13/fd18 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13/fd19 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13/fd20 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13/fd21 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd11.4/fd12/fd13/fd22 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd23/fd24/fd25/fd26/fd27/fd28.0/fd13/fd29 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd23/fd24/fd25/fd26/fd27/fd28.0/fd13/fd29/fd27 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd23/fd24/fd25/fd26/fd27/fd28.0/fd13/fd29/fd30 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd23/fd24/fd25/fd26/fd27/fd28.0/fd13 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd23/fd24/fd25/fd26/fd27/fd28.0/fd31 -isystemfd0/fd10/fd23/fd24/fd27/fd13 -Ifd0/fd1/fd2/fd3/fd4/fd32 -Ifd0/fd1/fd2/fd3/fd4 -Ifd0/fd1/fd2/fd3/fd4/fd32/fd33/fd13 -ferror-limit=0 -imacrosfd0/fd7/fd8/fd34/fd1/fd2/fd3/fd4/fd5/fd6.cpp /fd0/fd1/fd2/fd3/fd4/fd5/fd6.cpp
Clang-tidy config: {"Checks":"-*,cert-dcl21-cpp,cert-dcl58-cpp,cert-err34-c,cert-err52-cpp,cert-err58-cpp,cert-err60-cpp,cert-flp30-c,cert-msc50-cpp,cert-msc51-cpp,cert-str34-c,cppcoreguidelines-interfaces-global-init,cppcoreguidelines-narrowing-conversions,cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-member-init,cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-static-cast-downcast,cppcoreguidelines-slicing,google-default-arguments,google-explicit-constructor,google-runtime-operator,hicpp-exception-baseclass,hicpp-multiway-paths-covered,misc-misplaced-const,misc-new-delete-overloads,misc-no-recursion,misc-non-copyable-objects,misc-throw-by-value-catch-by-reference,misc-unconventional-assign-operator,misc-uniqueptr-reset-release,mpi-buffer-deref,mpi-type-mismatch,openmp-use-default-none,performance-faster-string-find,performance-for-range-copy,performance-implicit-conversion-in-loop,performance-inefficient-algorithm,performance-inefficient-string-concatenation,performance-inefficient-vector-operation,performance-move-const-arg,performance-move-constructor-init,performance-no-automatic-move,performance-noexcept-move-constructor,performance-trivially-destructible,performance-type-promotion-in-math-fn,performance-unnecessary-copy-initialization,performance-unnecessary-value-param,readability-avoid-const-params-in-decls,readability-const-return-type,readability-container-size-empty,readability-convert-member-functions-to-static,readability-delete-null-pointer,readability-deleted-default,readability-inconsistent-declaration-parameter-name,readability-make-member-function-const,readability-misleading-indentation,readability-misplaced-array-index,readability-non-const-parameter,readability-redundant-control-flow,readability-redundant-declaration,readability-redundant-function-ptr-dereference,readability-redundant-smartptr-get,readability-redundant-string-cstr,readability-redundant-string-init,readability-simplify-subscript-expr,readability-static-definition-in-anonymous-namespace,readability-string-compare,readability-uniqueptr-delete-release,readability-use-anyofallof,bugprone-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clion-*","CheckOptions":[]}
CLion clang-tidy config: {"Checks":"-*,clion-preprocessor-comment-check,clion-virtual-call-in-ctor-or-dtor,clion-empty-decl-or-stmt,clion-simplify,clion-argument-selection-defects","CheckOptions":[]}
Clazy config: level0
DFA Input: global
UnusedIncludesInspection: RemoveNotDirectlyUsed
PP Diagnostics: 



clangd crashed. PLEASE CONSIDER adding the following preprocessed files to the crash report.
Code and file paths will be obfuscated. By default, they will NOT be attached and they will NOT be sent.
Files that might cause failure:
file:///C:/Users/Orion/CLionProjects/QT/Source%20Files/main.cpp, compilerDiags=WAITING, highlightings=WAITING, DFAInput=WAITING, CLion-clang-tidy=WAITING, Clazy=WAITING, clang-tidy=WAITING


java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaLogger.error(IdeaLogger.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:194)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.daemon.clang.clangd.lsp.server.ClangCrashHandler$DefaultClangCrashReporter.report(ClangCrashHandler.java:1236)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.daemon.clang.clangd.lsp.server.ClangCrashHandler.lambda$doAdvancedCrashReport$6(ClangCrashHandler.java:360)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.daemon.clang.clangd.lsp.server.ClangCrashHandler.withCrashLanguageService(ClangCrashHandler.java:399)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.daemon.clang.clangd.lsp.server.ClangCrashHandler.doAdvancedCrashReport(ClangCrashHandler.java:332)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.daemon.clang.clangd.lsp.server.ClangCrashHandler.lambda$reportCrash$2(ClangCrashHandler.java:190)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.BackgroundTaskUtil.runUnderDisposeAwareIndicator(BackgroundTaskUtil.java:365)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.BackgroundTaskUtil.runUnderDisposeAwareIndicator(BackgroundTaskUtil.java:343)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.daemon.clang.clangd.lsp.server.ClangCrashHandler.lambda$reportCrash$3(ClangCrashHandler.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: It might be a bug with CLion, have you reported it to the vendor?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't received a response yet

Comment: I had a similar issue. What I need to do is delete `~/.config/clangd` folder with the config file created by QtCreator

Comment: I run into exactly the same problem, the log file shows an identical call stack. May you share your bug report link? I'd like to track their progress on this bug.

Comment: By the way, File | Repair IDE can also temporarily fix this problem, which might be a bit more convenient.